# Safari Mojave Post Request to another domain results in "Object moved to here."

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Our existing website makes a request to a different domain with a POST request. This request works fine for most browsers and once the request is made the *other* domain will tell the browser redirect to another page on its domain.

However, for MacOS Mojave Safari, the initial POST request results in the following response:

`HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily`

And the Safari browser will not move forward. The response from the other domain is to simply have our users upgrade to the latest browser. However, is there some sort of alternative approach that can be taken to support these Safari Mojave users from our end? Assuming we cannot change the actual POST request cycle that happens.

Comment: Did you found the solution??

Comment: Nope never did. Determined it was an issue with Safari.